# Want to publish the existing app on play store and app store having new functionality with new app name

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-play, app-store

Currently we have an existing flutter app published on app store and play store. What we want to achieve is while keeping the existing app published as it is but to publish a new app with additional functionality with new name on both play store and app store. What will be the procedure to achieve this, what steps needs to be taken and what documents we might need to do this.

Comment: you might want to try "flavors" for flutter. I'm not sure if that's exactly what you need. you can read about it [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors)